# Sveltekit node application renders no build folder. Only output folder with client & server folder inside

Tags: node.js, sveltekit

I want to deploy my sveltekit app on a node server but I can't seem to make it work.

I followed the documentation but they're all talking about a build folder but it just doesn't appear in my directory.

Is there an explaination for that?

This is my svelte.config file:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node'
import { vitePreprocess } from "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte";

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
  kit: {
    adapter: adapter()
  },
};

export default {
  preprocess: [vitePreprocess({})],
  config,
};
```